# Is there any way to add Autocorrect to my Android Keyboard?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, spelling

I am working on an Android Keyboard, and I was trying to see if there was any way to add in Autocorrect into it. Or is Autocorrect provided with the Spelling Checker Framework? I cannot find a clear cut answer anywhere on here or any other place that I have looked.

My code for my keyboard can be found here > https://github.com/MJonesDev/AndroidKeyboardPractice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rely on the Spellchecker framework.  It isn't included on all devices-  specifically Samsung ones.  (Which may be my fault-  when I worked at Swype and 4.0 was new, its UI was interacting badly with Swype.  I asked them to turn it off by default, they decided to remove it entirely).

Even when it exists it doesn't really provide autocorrect.  At best it can give you possibilities, and its then your job  to display them, and handle the text correction when one is chosen.

There are various spelling correction libraries out there of different qualities.  Its possible to find open source ones to include if you aren't looking to do anything special.

Comment: Okay, thank you. It's pretty strange why it isn't included on all devices standard as a core part of the Android OS.

Comment: It probably is, its just disabled, and any easy way of enabling it removed from the device.  The code is likely still there.

Comment: Also, its kind of a failed idea.  Autocorrect it too tied up with keyboards-  a good autocorrect for typing won't work for Swyping very well, because the types of mistakes you make on the two are different and the data you analyze is different.  In addition if for example Swiftkey has a much better tapping prediction due to research in n-grams, they don't want other keyboards to use it and negate their competitve advantage.  So they won't allow their algorithms to be used via the spellchecker framework.  Same for all the other keyboard companies.